# Suddenly, Android Studio start to show /* compiled code */ not detail

Tags: android-studio

[image]

As image I attached, Android studio does not show detail code about some library classes.
For example I cannot see the detail code about ```Iterable.filter````

Even though I click the "Download Sources" button and "Choose Sources", there is no luck.
It's totally not working.
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin is an open-source programming language, you can use Github and look through the source code in there.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned above, I can see the code via github. but I want to see the code in Android sutdio and know whether it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried decompiling to Java? And see if that makes a difference?